# First order approximation

Tags: expression-manipulation, approximation

How can I neglect higher orders of approximation in *Mathematica*?

Suppose I want to find the roots of a simple quadratic equation like

```
x^2 + (b + Epsilon)*x + c == 0
```

where `Epsilon << 1`. Obviously, the roots are

```
x -> 1/2 (-b - Epsilon - Sqrt[-4 c + (b + Epsilon)^2])
x -> 1/2 (-b - Epsilon + Sqrt[-4 c + (b + Epsilon)^2])
```

Now, how can I neglect `Epsilon^2`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) to specify the order of approximation.  When an expression involving the output of `Series`, which is a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) object, is evaluated, the calculus is done for you.

```
sol = Solve[x^2 + (b + Epsilon)*x + c == 0, x]
approx = sol /. Epsilon -> Series[Epsilon, {Epsilon, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you could apply `Series` to the formula directly (use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) to chop off the big-Oh term).

```
Series[x /. sol, {Epsilon, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]